# UIScrollView with Images

Tags: image, ios, uiscrollview

Hey! I've almost completed my app but I do need a UIScrollView with my images to finish it.
I want paging enabled so it will stop at every image.

And when you've scrolled to an image an action will be done. So say I scroll to the next image the app will do the action `imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MyFirstImage.png"];`

How would I do this?

And please be somewhat specific? :) I'm still a beginner

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can set a delegate to an UIScrollView object. It could be any object, but usually the view controller object of your view. Set the delegate in, say, viewDidLoad in the view controller like the following.

aScrOllView.delegate = self;

Then, implement delegate methods in the view controller defined in UIScrollViewDelegate protocol. Specifically you will be interested in scrollViewDIdEndDragging:willDecelerate: and scrollViewDidEndDecelerating because they are called when the scrolling has done. In these method, you can do whatever you need for scrolling inputs.

Comment: Ok, but how do I add the images?

Comment: Create an UIImageView containing the image you need. Then simply add it as a subview of your scroll view; In those delegate methods, you should get which region of the scroll view the user sees (you can use `contentOffset` property of your scroll view. Then you know where you should put the image in the scroll view's frame. However, you may want to load images for the previous/next page as well, so when the user starts scrolling, those images are ready and page transition looks okay. See `PageControl` sample project and `ScrollViewSuite` sample projects.